# Inserir valor no value do input ao expandir imagem com javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho o seguinte código (Função dele é expandir a imagem em uma `div` onde tem o `id` #expandedImg.

```
        function myFunction(imgs) {
            var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
            var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
            expandImg.src = imgs.src;
            imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
            expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
            $("#expandedImg").attr('value', imgs.alt );
        }
```

Funciona perfeitamente, mas eu queria implementar que quando ele expande a imagem ele também pega o `alt` da imagem (O que funciona) e adicione dentro de um value de um input com hidden.

Já tentei diversos códigos para adicionar o valor do alt no value mas não consegui.

Abaixo meu código completo:

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";

  //O quero implementar
  $("#expandedImg").attr('value', imgs.alt);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Expanding image text */

#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
<img class="excluirImagem" id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
<form>
  <input id="expandedImg" type="hidden" name="excluirImagem" value="">
  <button type="submit">Excluir imagem</button>

</form>
<div id="imgtext"></div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vc está usando o mesmo id `expandedImg` na imagem e no input, por isso o problema. O valor está sendo inserido na imagem e não no input.

Comment: Não tinha pensado nisso, de certa forma é lógico. Então por isso consegui usando outro `id` para o input.

Comment: Nem precisa colocar um id no input, pode pegar pelo `name` mesmo: `$("[name=excluirImagem]")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `expandImg.value` para receber o valor.

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";

  //O quero implementar
  expandImg.value =  imgs.alt
  console.log("Valor do hidden: " +  document.getElementById("expandedImg").value);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Expanding image text */

#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
<img class="excluirImagem" id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
<form>
  <input id="expandedImg" type="hidden" name="excluirImagem" value="">
  <button type="submit">Excluir imagem</button>

</form>
<div id="imgtext"></div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sim, já tinha tentado deste forma, mas não consigo levar esse value em um formulário.

Comment: Consegui definindo exatamente como meu input está: function myFunction(imgs) {
            var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
            var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
            expandImg.src = imgs.src;
            imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
            expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
            expandImg.value = imgs.alt;
            $('input[type=hidden].excluirImagem').val(imgs.alt);
        }

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu, mais note que você está sentando duas vezes o valor para o input hidde. Uma através do Javascript: expandImg.value = imgs.alt; e outra através do Jquery $('input[type=hidden].excluirImagem').val(imgs.alt);

Comment: Sim, já corrigi, agora está tudo certo.